# Generate shared secret key from Curve25519 (or X25519) asymmetric key pairs in node.js using crypto module

Tags: node.js, encryption, cryptography, diffie-hellman, curve-25519

I am trying to create a shared secret key between [**Curve25519 (or X25519) asymmetric key**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curve25519) pairs using key exchange algorithms just like [**Diffie Hellman** key exchange](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffie%E2%80%93Hellman_key_exchange). **Diffie Hellman** key exchange can be be done in node.js using crypto module in the following [code](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_diffiehellman_computesecret_otherpublickey_inputencoding_outputencoding):

```
const crypto = require('crypto');

// Generate Alice's keys...
const alice = crypto.createDiffieHellman(2048);
const aliceKey = alice.generateKeys(); // Returns public key

// Generate Bob's keys...
const bob = crypto.createDiffieHellman(alice.getPrime(), alice.getGenerator());
const bobKey = bob.generateKeys(); // Returns public key

// Exchange and generate the secret...
const aliceSecret = alice.computeSecret(bobKey);
const bobSecret = bob.computeSecret(aliceKey);

// Should be equal
console.log(aliceSecret === bobSecret)
```

**X25519 asymmetric keys** can be generated using the following [code](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_generatekeypairsync_type_options):

```
const crypto = require('crypto');
const { publicKey, privateKey } = crypto.generateKeyPairSync('x25519', {
  publicKeyEncoding: {
    type: 'spki',
    format: 'pem'
  },
  privateKeyEncoding: {
    type: 'pkcs8',
    format: 'pem',
  }
});
```

The keys are generated without any issue but I don't know how to generate a shared secret key.
I tried converting X25519 keys to **Diffie Hellman** keys using the folowing code:

```
...
const dhKey= crypto.createDiffieHellman(2048);
// privateKey => Generated in the above code
dhKey.setPrivateKey(privateKey)
// publicKey => Generated in the above code
dhKey.setPublicKey(publicKey)
...
```

When using the above code when two dhKey are generated and key exchange is performed, it is giving the following error:

```
Error: Supplied key is too large
```

Is there any way the shared secret can be generated?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It already is a diffie-hellman key, you should not be attempting to convert it. Just use the diffie-hellman methods on it.

Comment: While creating normal diffie hellman key from crypto module curve25519 key is not created and i want to use curve25519 key which is only created by generateKeyPairSync() and there is no method supported with this type of key generation to compute shared secret.

Comment: My apologies, unfortunately it was not as simple as I thought.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The documentation for this sub API is unfortunately a little thin. I cobbled together an example but without better documentation I'm not sure it's useful.

```js
const crypto = require('crypto');

const aliceKeyPair = crypto.generateKeyPairSync('x25519');

const alicePubExport = aliceKeyPair.publicKey.export(
    {type: 'spki', format: 'pem'}
    );

const bobKeyPair = crypto.generateKeyPairSync('x25519');

const bobPubExport = bobKeyPair.publicKey.export(
    {type: 'spki', format: 'pem'}
    );

const bobKeyAgree = crypto.diffieHellman({
    publicKey : crypto.createPublicKey(alicePubExport),
    privateKey: bobKeyPair.privateKey
});

const aliceKeyAgree = crypto.diffieHellman({
    publicKey : crypto.createPublicKey(bobPubExport),
    privateKey: aliceKeyPair.privateKey
});

console.log(bobKeyAgree.toString('hex'));
console.log(aliceKeyAgree.toString('hex'));
```

This is missing authentication and therefore is not secure without adding that piece.

Comment: I tried the code it worked but there is a slight issue. When I added cipher and passphrase to [**privateKeyEncoding**](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_generatekeypairsync_type_options) while generating the keys, I am getting errors like  "Assertion `!errors_.empty()' failed."